# Increment, Decrement Value In A Foreach Loop Using Vue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a problem in my project. I want to Increment, Decrement Value in a foreach Loop, Here is my code

```
<div class="booking__left__content__addons__content__card" v-for="addOn in addOnGroup.addOns">
<div class="booking-quantity">
    <div class="booking-quantity__inner">
        <input type="button" class="qty-button qty-button__minus" v-on:click="decrementAddOn($event, addOn.pivot.id)">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="selectedGroupedAddOns[addOn.pivot.id]" placeholder="1">
        <input type="button" class="qty-button qty-button__plus" v-on:click="incrementAddOn($event, addOn.pivot.id)">
    </div>
</div>
```

And My Vue Code Is

```
incrementAddOn(event, key) {
    this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]++;
},

decrementAddOn(event, key) {
    if(this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key] > 0) { 
        this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]--;
    }
},
```

The code is not working. And in My console I get that `this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]` is `undefined`

Comment: Can you provide data from `this.selectedGroupedAddOns`?

Comment: I did not get any value in `this.selectedGroupedAddOns`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting undefined on console for `this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]` then the `addOn.pivot.id parameter` is mostly undefined or that value is not existing in your `selectedGroupedAddOns` array.

Check the value of `addOn.pivot.id` in console first.

To add counter value on id's update methods as below.

```
incrementAddOn(event, key) {
if(this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]){
    this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]++;
} else {
    this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key] = 1;
}
},

decrementAddOn(event, key) {
    if(this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key] && this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key] > 0 ) { 
        this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key]--;
    } else {
        this.selectedGroupedAddOns[key] = 0;
    }
},
```

Comment: There exists value in `addOn.pivot.id` but not getting any value `this.selectedGroupedAddOns`

Comment: You mean you do get a valid value for console.log(key) within the function.

Comment: Kindly post your selectedGroupedAddOns  array data.

Comment: My `selectedGroupedAddOns` is null. `data() {
 return {
  selectedGroupedAddOns : []
 }
},`

Comment: That means your array is empty to increment a value in array first you need some value in the array itself.

Comment: What are you trying to increment then????? Do you want a counter value on ids?

Comment: Yes. I want a counter value on ids